# ASP.NET Image Control not updated after ImageUrl change

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, imageurl

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET and of course happened to stumble some strange problem.
Problem is very popular, but none of the replies I found worked for me.

I have a simple image:

```
<asp:Image ID="userImage" runat="server" ImageAlign="Right" />
```

And in codebehind:

```
If Not Session("selecteduser") Is Nothing Then
    userImage.ImageUrl = "~/showphoto.aspx?user=" & Session("selecteduser")
End If
```

And the image doesn't change. It doesn't even fire up the showphoto.aspx code.
The property is changed (because next time i step into it, it's changed), but showphoto is never fired.

I'm aware of image caching issues, but I can't get even one image, not mentioning have it changed.
For sure there's a very simple explanation, but I'm fighting with this for 2 days now to no avail.

Comment: Right click on the html page, on web, and see the rendered code - see there the final path of your image, and what is try to called. Also you can you firebug or inspection tools on google chrome to see what is looking for.

Comment: @Aristos - the problem is there is no change in client-side path. The changed ImageUrl property is only visible on the server-side (codebehind).

Comment: is the code that changes the ImageUrl executed?

Comment: What do you see on the html rendered page ? can you post it here ? eg <img src="/showphoto?user=">

Comment: @shrutyzet - yes, it's being executed, and I can see previous execution result in debug.@Aristos - showphoto.aspx works fine when used manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be one of the following:

1. There is nothing in the session object "selecteduser" which might cause that the imageurl property not set. ( Resolution: debug your code to confirm that there is a session object )
2. The image url is being setted but the image is not changed which might be a problem of browser caching. (Resolution: Append the current date time to the list of query string parameters to force the browser to load the new image).
3. "showphoto.aspx" is a page and not an image so it return html code which is not translated to image. (Resolution:Change the content-type property of this page to be image

Comment: 1. Confirmed (I can even use static text and still doesn't work), 2. Will try, 3. showphoto.aspx is using response.binarywrite to write back jpg, and works flawlessy on it's own.

Comment: try adding this as well `context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");`

Comment: try using `userImage.ImageUrl = "showphoto.aspx?user=" & Session("selecteduser")` OR `userImage.ImageUrl = "/showphoto.aspx?user=" & Session("selecteduser")`

Comment: changing the path didn't help

Comment: If you can put the whole code for both pages, i will put them on my development machine and i will debug the problem and post to you the correct code.

Comment: @Samir_Adel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1621/discussion-between-ufoq-and-samir-adel)

Comment: Sorry, can't do that. Company policy forbids that. Project is very small, but it includes connecting to HR DB and AD, so pretty sensitive. I will try to extract offending code into side-project and post here.